# How can i compare values in an array and show them from greater to lower in ARM Assembly?

Tags: assembly, arm

I want to compare an array of 100 numbers and print them from greater to lower. This is the code i'm using:

```
loop:
    cmp r2, #100
    bleq compNum
    moveq r5, #0
    ldr r0,=formatoF
    bl scanf
    mov r3, r1, lsl #1
    str r2, [r3]
    add r2, r2, #1
    b loop
compNum:
    cmp r5, #100
    bleq fin
    mov r4, [r3], lsl #1

    ldr r0, =formatNum
    ldr r1, [r3], lsl #1
    bl printf
    add r5, r5, #1

    b compNum
```

But when i try to compile it, this message shows up:

```
subR.s:18: Error: immediate expression requires a # prefix -- `mov r4,[r3],lsl#1'
subR.s:21: Error: immediate expression requires a # prefix -- `ldr r1,[r3],lsl#1'
```

How can i compare them and print them?

Comment: I assume this is the syntax you are after? [<Rn>], +/-<Rm>, <shift> #<shift_imm>  you need a register in there...

Comment: are you looking for unsigned lower or signed lower?

Comment: Im looking for unsigned lower

Comment: which register were you wanting to shift left by two at the end of the operation?

Comment: The register R3, which is the one containing the array

Comment: so then look at the arm docs which show my first comment ldr r1,[r3],r3,lsl #1 assembles just fine...

Comment: that wont make it walk through the array though you probably want ldr r1,[r3],#4 or something like that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help I totally forgot that instruction